# Numpy interfering with namespace

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, namespaces

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    x /= 10

data = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
print data
f(data)
print data
```

Output on my system (debian 8, Python 2.7.9-1, numpy 1:1.8.2-2)

```
[ 0. 0.25  0.5   0.75  1.  ]
[ 0. 0.025  0.05   0.075  0.1  ]
```

Normally I would expect `data` to stay untouched when passing it to a function as this has its own separate namespace. But when the data is a numpy array the function changes `data` globally.

Is this a feature, a bug or am I maybe missing something? How should I avoid this behavior when using a custom plot function to scale my data automatically?

**UPDATE**
(*See Kevin J. Chase's answer for more details*)

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    print id(x)
    x = x/10
    print id(x)

data = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
print id(data)
print data
f(data)
print data
```

Output on my system (debian 8, Python 2.7.9-1, numpy 1:1.8.2-2)

```
48844592
[ 0. 0.25  0.5   0.75  1.  ]
48844592
45972592
[ 0. 0.25  0.5   0.75  1.  ]
```

Using `x = x/10` instead of `x /= 10` solves the problem for me.

The behaviour of the nice and short `x /= 10` statement actually depends heavily on the *type of x*. It rebinds if x is immutable and mutates otherwise.

It is not equivalent to `x = x/10` which always rebinds.

A numpy array is a mutable object.

Comment: Can you paste the output?  I'm not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: If I remove the 2 `matplotlib` lines (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.plot(x)`), then still I get the same output as you do

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Was not suspecting numpy. Question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Normally I would expect data to stay untouched when passing it to a function as this has its own separate namespace.

`x` in the function and `data` at the module level are two names for the *same* object.  Since that object is mutable, any changes made to it will be "seen" regardless of which name is used to refer to the object.  Namespaces can't protect you from that.

`x /= 10` divides every element of the NumPy array by 10.  The original data is gone after this line executes.  If you were to run `f(data)` a few more times, you'd find the contents draw closer to 0.0 each time.

Lists are a more familiar example of the same effect:

```
l = list(range(4))
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
l += [4]
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For a good overview of this sort of thing (including related issues) I recommend Ned Batchelder's “[Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)” (26 minute [video from PyCon US 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns)).  His example of list "addition" starts about 10 minutes in.

## Behind the Scenes

`/` and `/=` (and similar pairs of operators) do different things.  Tutorials often claim that these two operations are the same:

```
x = x / 10
x /= 10
```

...but they're not.  Full details can be found in [*The Python Language Reference*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/), [3.3.7.  Emulating Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

`/` calls the `__truediv__` (or maybe `__rtruediv__` --- a topic for another day) method on one of the two objects, feeding the other object as the argument:

```
# x = x / 10
x = x.__truediv__(10)
```

Typically, these methods return some new value without altering the old one.  This is why `data` was unchanged by `x / 10`, but `id(x)` changed --- `x` now referred to a new object, and was no longer an alias for `data`.

`/=` calls a completely different method, `__itruediv__` for the "in-place" operation:

```
# x /= 10
x = x.__itruediv__(10)
```

*These* methods typically modify the object, which then returns `self`.  This explains why `id(x)` was unchanged *and* why `data`'s contents had changed --- `x` and `data` were still the one and only object.  From the docs I linked above:

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying `self`) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, `self`).  If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods  [meaning `__add__` and family --- *KJC*].

If you look at the methods of different data types, you'll find that they don't support all of these.

- `dir(0)` shows that integers lack the in-place methods, which shouldn't be surprising, because they're immutable.
- `dir([])` reveals only two in-place methods: `__iadd__` and `__imul__` --- you can't divide or subtract from a list, but you can in-place add another list, and you can multiply it by an integer.  (Again, those methods can do whatever they want with their arguments, including refuse them...  `list.__iadd__` won't take an integer, while `list.__imul__` will reject a list.)
- `dir(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))` shows basically *all* of the arithmetic, logic, and bitwise methods, with normal and in-place for each.  (It could be missing some --- I didn't count them all.)

Finally, to re-reiterate, what namespace these objects are in when their methods get called makes absolutely no difference.  In Python, data has *no scope*... if you have a reference to it, you can call methods on it.  (From Ned Batchelder's talk:  Variables have a scope, but no type; data has a type, but no scope.)

Comment: I don't understand your list example. You are appending a new element to your list. My Problem is, that a invoked functioin should only be able to make "local" changes inside the function unless global variables or return statements are used otherwise - at least that is what I always thaught.

Comment: @Felix:  That's exactly what happened --- `f` made "local" changes to the data you gave it.  It is _exactly_ the same as the list example.  Again, namespaces have nothing to do with this.  The fact that the _one and only_ copy of the data was mutated inside a function has nothing to do with this.

Comment: But f makes global changes to the object it is given when using the nice and short `a x= b` statements instead of the longer `a = axb` statements. Until now I believed these were equivalent as stated in most places like here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm  ... bug or feature?

Comment: @Felix:  In my list example, `lst += [5]` is "equivalent" to `lst = lst + [5]` (try it).  I could call that list `susan` or `not_a_list` or even `immutable_forever`... doesn't change the fact that it's a list, and its contents have changed.  (This doesn't seem to happen to integers or strings, because they're immutable.)  I put "equivalent" in scare-quotes because they're _not_ actually the same.  `+` calls an object's `__add__` or `__radd__` method, while `+=` calls its `__iadd__` "in-place addition" method.  (Those methods _could_ do whatever they want...)

Comment: Can you please stick to the given problem and not talk about yours. When `x /= b` is invoked depending on the type of x (immutable or not) a rebind or mutation is made. So this is *not* equivalent to `x = x/b`.

Comment: @Felix:  No, they're not equivalent.  I thought I made that clear.  I've updated my answer to explain the difference.

Comment: @Felix: Also, immutability is only part of it.  Immutable types can't mutate (by definition), but mutable types could mutate or stay the same, depending on how they implemented their `__iadd__` or whatever method... assuming they even have one.